# $.ajax result getting as [Object object]

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I used `$.ajax` function for passing data to php

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://artinnmedia.com/index/get_gallery",
         data: {movie_id:id},
         complete: function(json){
             alert(json);
          }
      });
```

and the php code is

```
    $id =$this->input->get('movie_id');
$movie=$this->site_model->get_movie_single($id);
extract($movie[0]);
    if($gallery_id==null)
    {   
    print 0;
    }

    else
    {
    print $gallery_id;
    }
```

now the problem is the result is getting in the `$.ajax` function as `[Object object]`. How can I get it as plain text

Comment: what is `$gallery_id`

Comment: Why? You can use JSON.stringify if you really need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://artinnmedia.com/index/get_gallery",
         data: {movie_id:id},

         complete: function(json){
             console.log(json); // check data here in your browser console.
          }
      });
```

You can check the output in your browser console. you can use `ctrl + shift + J` in Google Chrome Browser

Comment: OP did say they wanted a string. You're assuming they just want to inspect it

Comment: @JuanMendes `How can I get it as plain text` doesn't mean that they want the output in `string`.. Secondly `ctrl + shift + J` is just a suggestion to check the output produced by `console.log` and they can trivers the object to take out what they want..

Comment: Plain text is usually a string.  That may be what the OP wanted but it's not what they asked

Answer (score 4):

use [success](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), instead, like:

```
success: function(json){
    console.log(json);
}
```

Comment: I think they both pass a JSON object if your data is JSON, don't they? I think the safe way is to use the jqxhr argument and read its responseText property